# Appending an argument to request_uri for mobile subdomain on nginx

Tags: nginx, subdomain, mediawiki, mobile-devices, cors

I'm running a multilingual wiki (MediaWiki 1.26.2 with [MobileFrontend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:MobileFrontend)) on nginx 1.9.3/OpenBSD 5.8.

For each language wiki, I have a separate MediaWiki installation folder and a subdomain like en.domain.com pointing to that folder.

I'd like to add a subdomain like en.m.domain.com for the mobile view using the MediaWiki installation folder of the desktop view but with an appended `&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile` (or `?mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile` with a question mark instead of an ampersand if there is already an argument).

I'm also using CORS, [short URLs](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL) and redirects from `http://` to `https://`.

This is how my server block looks like:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name en.m.domain.com;
    root /path/to/domain/en;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    autoindex off;

# CORS
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'X-Requested-With, Accept, Content-Type, Origin';

# Redirect to https://

    if ($http_cf_visitor ~ '{"scheme":"http"}') {
        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        }

    location = / {
        return 301 https://en.m.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page;
        }

    location = /w {
        return 301 https://en.m.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page;
        }

    location = /w/ {
        return 301 https://en.m.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page;
        }

    location = /wiki {
        return 301 https://en.m.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page;
        }

    location = /wiki/ {
        return 301 https://en.m.domain.com/wiki/Main_Page;
        }

# Short URLs

    location / {
        index index.php;
        error_page 404 = @mediawiki;
        }

    location @mediawiki {
        rewrite ^/wiki([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /w/index.php?title=$1&$2 last;
        }

    location ~ \.php5?$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1234;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

    location ~ \.php?$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:1234;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }

# Append mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile for mobile version

    location / {                                                   

        # If there are no arguments add a question mark
        if ($args = '') {                                            
        set $new_request_uri "$request_uri?mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile";  
        }                                                            

        # If there are already arguments add an ampersand
        if ($args != "") {      
        set $new_request_uri "$request_uri&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile";  
        }

        rewrite $new_request_uri last;        
        }       

}
```

Unfortunately the `mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile` part doesn't work :(

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks and cheers,

Till

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your current implementation: you have two `location /` blocks and `rewrite $new_request_uri last;` is semantically incorrect.

The easy solution is to modify the `$request_uri` by performing an *external redirect*. This is messy because you need to identify only those URIs which do not have a `mobileaction` argument. For example:

```
if ($args !~* mobileaction) {
    rewrite ^ $uri?mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile permanent;
}
```

The `rewrite` directive takes care of `?` vs `&` and automatically appends the existing argument list.

The `if` block could be placed inside the `location /` block or above it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast help! And if I want nginx to look exactly for `mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile`, I need to change the first line to `if ($arg_mobileaction !~* toggle_view_mobile) {`, right?

And is it possible to make `mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile` invisible for short URLs? I tried `rewrite ^/wiki([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /w/index.php?title=$1&$2&mobileaction=toggle_view_mobile last;` and `rewrite ^/wiki([^?]*)(?:\?(.*))? /w/index.php?title=$1&$args last;` but that didn't work :(

Comment: Yes. And you're right - it doesn't work, which is why I suggested the external redirect method. An internal method would involve looking inside the `fastcgi_params` file and replacing REQUEST_URI with something new.

Comment: Thank you for your help! However, I stopped trying to use a subdomain for the mobile version for now, since I can't do it so easily with Cloudflare anyway. My website just shows the desktop or mobile version depending on the user's device. I think that's fine too.